# How to access content page control from master page in asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net

I have a literal Control in my default.aspx, and i want to access this from my masterpage.When i try to do this,i got null exception error(object reference missing).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FindControl` in your master page.

Content page:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="myLiteral"></asp:Literal>
```

And in your master page load (or other place):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var myLiteral = ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("myLiteral");
    if (myLiteral != null) {
        ((Literal)myLiteral).Text = "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Where `ContentPlaceHolder1` is the ID of your placeholder in the master page.